# Getting this protocol error using javax mail and apache commons

Tags: java, email

I have this java class in my project meant to send emails, but it doesn't matter what i try to do, it simply will fail into some protocol error.

Keep in mind that all i need is a simple email sender, it's for a school project.

This is the class i'm using:

```
import org.apache.commons.mail.*;


public class javaMail
{
    protected static String emailEmpresarial = "email@hotmail.com";
    protected static String senha = "password";
    
    public static void sendMail(String emailCliente)
    {


        SimpleEmail email = new SimpleEmail(); 
        email.setHostName("smtp-mail.outlook.com");
        email.setSmtpPort(587);
        email.setAuthenticator(new DefaultAuthenticator(emailEmpresarial, senha));
        email.setStartTLSRequired(true);
        
        try 
        {
            
            email.setFrom(emailEmpresarial);
            email.setSubject("Test");
            email.setMsg("Success!");
            email.addTo(emailCliente);
            email.send();
            System.out.println("Enviado com sucesso!");
            
        } catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

But this is what i'm getting:

> org.apache.commons.mail.EmailException: Sending the email to the following server failed : smtp-mail.outlook.com:587
> at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.sendMimeMessage(Email.java:1469)
> at org.apache.commons.mail.Email.send(Email.java:1496)
> at internetConnectionAPIs.javaMail.sendMail(javaMail.java:36)
> at App.main(App.java:12)
> Caused by: javax.mail.MessagingException: Could not convert socket to TLS;
> nested exception is:
> javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.startTLS(SMTPTransport.java:1918)
> at com.sun.mail.smtp.SMTPTransport.protocolConnect(SMTPTransport.java:652)
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: No appropriate protocol (protocol is disabled or cipher suites are inappropriate)

I tried to change to gmail(but it seems that it no longer works), try to change port, tried to change server, but it simply won't work, any ideas why? I'm using eclipse in focal fossa linux, and my project have javax mail, apache commons email and activation jar.

I even tried to ChatGPT it out of this, but to no avail. I tried to check for firewall blocks but there was no problem, i was using setSSLonConnect but it was forcing the port to be 465 even tho i've set it to 587, but after removing it, same error. Gmail is not being allowed to ''lesser security apps'' now, and i can only resort to other services, if you have any idea how to help, i'll be more than glad.

Also i'm very newbie to java and to this kind of error treating, i tried this following a youtube tutorial which was really plain and simple, and weirdly didn't need activation jar library, but my project needed it. I checked internet connection but it was working just fine. Do i need to connect eclipse to the internet or something like that?

All I am trying to do is just send a plain email, just that, I just need to implement an email sender for a school project, what do this no appropriate protocol means?

Well, I don't have anything to add to it anymore, stackoverflow is still asking me to add more details, this is what I have and I simply can't work it out.

PS: My java version is 11, could it be the issue?
Also, please don't mind the email and password hard coded to the program, it was meant to be just for testing.

Comment: Check your SMTP configuration. The error shows that you have used TLS but your SMTP server doesn't support it.

Comment: According to https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/office/pop-imap-and-smtp-settings-8361e398-8af4-4e97-b147-6c6c4ac95353, the combination of "smtp-mail.outlook.com" + port 587 + STARTTLS should be correct.  So, maybe it is a SSL/TLS version mismatch or a ciphersuite mismatch.

Comment: Is there a way i can fix this mismatch?

Answer (score 0):

I have used your code as is (besides user and password) and it works perfectly.

This must be an environment thing related to the availability of TLS1.2. Which version of Java are you using?

Add the following to your code to get more logging and add the logs to your question:

```
email.setDebug(true);
```

Comment: Did that, same error, sadly

Comment: I have updated my answer - your code is fine. This issue must be environment related. Up the debugging.

Comment: hello thank you, i managed to fix the problem! I needed to input specific cipher suits into properties and authenticate password using javax mail session